# How to get a xml file from a web url for Element Parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, ios4

I'm using Element parser to parse some xml from a local file right now but I'm wanting to be able to retrive this xml file from the web and then parse it with Element Parser. However, my app crashes when I try to use NSURL to get the xml file. So far the code I was trying to use was:

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://example.com/file.xml"]
```

The code I use for retrieving the local xml file is:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"file" ofType: @"xml"];
NSStringEncoding encoding;
self.source = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path usedEncoding: &encoding error:     NULL];
DocumentRoot *document = [Element parseXML:source];
```

So how can this be done? I also tried to do parseXMLFromURL but it doesn't work so I'm lost. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where is the documentation for this parser you're using? I googled it and can't find any reference to "Element" parser.

Comment: The only documentation is from here: http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSString *stringUrl = @"http://yourDomain.com/yourXml"
    NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[stringUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:finalURL    
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                      error:nil];
```